# VBA QueryTables not working with Yahoo Finance

Tags: excel, vba, yahoo-finance

I'm trying this simple Sub (in Excel 2019) to import tables from a specific Yahoo Finance page.

It works with other websites, but with Yahoo Finance, I keep getting the same message "This Web query returned no data. To change..........." and no data is extracted.

I couldn't figure out the reason.

```
Sub ImportTable()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim qt As QueryTable
Dim qurl As String


qurl = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/key-statistics?p=MSFT"
Set ws = worksheets.Add    

Set qt = ws.QueryTables.Add( _
    Connection:="URL;" & qurl, _
    Destination:=Range("A1"))
    
With qt
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .Name = "test"
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
    .Refresh
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can instead set-up connections to the various tables which will add them to the data model (Alt + B + M). In the queries pane of data you can then chose where to load them to your workbook if you wish to see them. You can also just work with them in the data model and generate your final desired output.

---

Note:

The quicker way is, from ribbon, to do, `data > from web` > enter url > select tables of interest. This will set-up table connections without vba.

---

VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AddYahooFinanceTableConnections()
    
    Dim wb As ThisWorkbook
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
 
    wb.Queries.Add Name:="Balance Sheet", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/key-statistics?p=MSFT""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data10 = Source{10}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data10,{{""Total Cash (mrq)"", type text}, {""131.99B"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    wb.Queries.Add Name:="Cash Flow Statement", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/key-statistics?p=MSFT""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data11 = Source{11}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data11,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    wb.Queries.Add Name:="Dividends & Splits", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/key-statistics?p=MSFT""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data5 = Source{5}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data5,{{""Forward Annual Dividend Rate"", type text}, {""2.24"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    wb.Queries.Add Name:="Fiscal Year", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/key-statistics?p=MSFT""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data6 = Source{6}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data6,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type date}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    wb.Queries.Add Name:="Income Statement", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/key-statistics?p=MSFT""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data9 = Source{9}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data9,{{""Revenue (ttm)"", type text}, {""153.28B"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    wb.Queries.Add Name:="People Also Watch", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/key-statistics?p=MSFT""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data12 = Source{12}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data12,{{""Symbol"", type text}, {""Last Price"", type number}, {""Change"", type number}, {""% Change"", Percentage.Type}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    wb.Queries.Add Name:="Profitability", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/key-statistics?p=MSFT""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data7 = Source{7}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data7,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", Percentage.Type}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    wb.Queries.Add Name:="Share Statistics", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/key-statistics?p=MSFT""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data4 = Source{4}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data4,{{""Avg Vol (3 month)"", type text}, {""30.36M"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    wb.Queries.Add Name:="Stock Price History", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/key-statistics?p=MSFT""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data3 = Source{3}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data3,{{""Beta (5Y Monthly)"", type text}, {""0.79"", type number}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    wb.Queries.Add Name:="Table 0", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/key-statistics?p=MSFT""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data0 = Source{0}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data0,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    wb.Queries.Add Name:="Table 1", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/key-statistics?p=MSFT""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data1 = Source{1}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data1,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    wb.Connections.Add2 "Query - Balance Sheet", _
        "Connection to the 'Balance Sheet' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Balance Sheet;Extended Properties=" _
        , """Balance Sheet""", 6, True, False
    wb.Connections.Add2 "Query - Cash Flow Statement", _
        "Connection to the 'Cash Flow Statement' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Cash Flow Statement;Extended Properties=" _
        , """Cash Flow Statement""", 6, True, False
    wb.Connections.Add2 "Query - Dividends & Splits", _
        "Connection to the 'Dividends & Splits' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Dividends & Splits;Extended Properties=" _
        , """Dividends & Splits""", 6, True, False
    wb.Connections.Add2 "Query - Fiscal Year", _
        "Connection to the 'Fiscal Year' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Fiscal Year;Extended Properties=" _
        , """Fiscal Year""", 6, True, False
    wb.Connections.Add2 "Query - Income Statement", _
        "Connection to the 'Income Statement' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Income Statement;Extended Properties=" _
        , """Income Statement""", 6, True, False
    wb.Connections.Add2 "Query - People Also Watch", _
        "Connection to the 'People Also Watch' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=People Also Watch;Extended Properties=" _
        , """People Also Watch""", 6, True, False
    wb.Connections.Add2 "Query - Profitability", _
        "Connection to the 'Profitability' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Profitability;Extended Properties=" _
        , """Profitability""", 6, True, False
    wb.Connections.Add2 "Query - Share Statistics", _
        "Connection to the 'Share Statistics' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Share Statistics;Extended Properties=" _
        , """Share Statistics""", 6, True, False
    wb.Connections.Add2 "Query - Stock Price History", _
        "Connection to the 'Stock Price History' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Stock Price History;Extended Properties=" _
        , """Stock Price History""", 6, True, False
    wb.Connections.Add2 "Query - Table 0", _
        "Connection to the 'Table 0' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Table 0;Extended Properties=" _
        , """Table 0""", 6, True, False
    wb.Connections.Add2 "Query - Table 1", _
        "Connection to the 'Table 1' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Table 1;Extended Properties=" _
        , """Table 1""", 6, True, False
  
End Sub
```